# iPhone: Multiple Choice - How to Avoid two or more answers touched?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have a program that has multiple choice, i.e., 4 basic buttons where you press the right choice. (Each button has a TouchUpInside event which calls an IBAction to check if the answer was correct)

But the problem I noticed is that the user can press down on two buttons at the same time, or even all 4 (and they all fire the IBAction).

Is there a way for me to only allow one choice to be picked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

`button_i.exclusiveTouch = YES;`

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best option when multiple answers are touched is to refuse to accept any of them. If the user touched two answers by accident, for example, you don't want to try to guess which one he or she meant to select. Your app should refuse any ambiguous input.

You might implement that by delaying acceptance of the answer until a short time has passed, maybe 0.2 or 0.3 seconds. If you get a second touch immediately after the first, then, you'd ignore both.

This seems particularly important in a situation where the user gets immediate feedback about the correct answer. You have a little more flexibility if the user has an opportunity to change their mind. If you present multiple questions, for example, and let the user go back and change answers until all the questions are completed, then you can clearly afford to take just the first or last answer that was touched. You could use a similar strategy even when the user gets immediate feedback by providing a "submit" button, so that the user could settle on the answer he or she wants to select, and only then hits a button to commit the answer.

Comment: While this is sound design advice, this doesn't necessarily solve the problem. If the user knows that the first tapped answer is the only one accepted, they won't keep trying to break the system.

Comment: @Moshe, I think it's better to design according to [Hanlon's razor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hanlon's_razor) and simply build a system that tolerates faulty input. For every user that tries to break the app, there will be dozens that simply make mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest keeping a boolean value around which is set off when the first IBAction is fired. You could do something like this:

In your interface:

```
BOOL questionWasAnswered;
```

When you set up your view, make sure to set it to `NO`. Then, in each IBAction, you can do the following:

```
 if(questionWasAnswered){
   return;
 }else{
    questionWasAnswered = YES;
 }

 //...Run the rest of your method
```